# Click on button pops up share mobile phone window html

Tags: php, html

I'm programing a page in php...and I'm allocating a button named "share"

I've seen in twitter mobile website that if you click on this "share" button it pops up the mobile window to share the tweet...in some other applications...how is this possible?

How do I connect this html button with the share window of mobile phones? [image]

Comment: Please post what code you have so far.

Comment: what do you mean by window of mobile phones? are you need it in responsive page or mobile application?

Comment: I mean this cellphone window that shows all the applications you can share some content, it usually appears after clicking share in an app, but  not in a html layout in a website. Twitter mobile version has that feature. Im talking from the browser.

Comment: I took an screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s done via the **Web Share API**.

Couple of links to get started:

https://wicg.github.io/web-share/

https://codeburst.io/the-web-share-api-is-here-cb651d84eccd

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/navigator-share

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share

http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/getting-started-with-the-web-share-api/10156

Comment: That was what I meant. Awesome!!